# how to get permission to re-write in /data/data/app_name/lib/abc.so folder to add extra .so files

Tags: android

I am trying to add `.so`  files . in `data/data/aap_package/lib`   folder  but i am getting error   `/data/data/mobiwise.myapplication/lib/libaacdecoder.so`: `open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)`

Comment: Have to define the permission ?

Answer (score 0):

Ask permission using below method...

```
 public static boolean checkPermissionForAccess(Activity activity, String[] requirePermission, int requestCode) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

        ArrayList<String> permissionArray = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String aRequirePermission : requirePermission) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, aRequirePermission)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                permissionArray.add(aRequirePermission);
            }
        }

        if (permissionArray.size() > 0) {
            String[] requestPermission;
            requestPermission = permissionArray.toArray(new String[permissionArray.size()]);
            activity.requestPermissions(requestPermission, requestCode);
        } else {
//                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permission Granted M", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
    } else {
//            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permission Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}



if (Utils.checkPermissionForAccess(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1)) {
            //perform something
        }
```

Comment: taking permission to write on external storage did not work, what else I should ask for permission?

Comment: also write ` <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>` in menifest..

Comment: Not Working, store that file(.so) in internal storage.. /data/data/mobiwise.myapplication/lib/libaacdecoder.so:

Answer (score 0):

Store in on your internal storage -no permission needed- and loaded with `System.load()`

Comment: how to store it by use the System.load() method, do you have any example

Comment: You store it by downloading the lib to a certain folder, for example the internal storage of your application. Afterwards, fetch the path of the lib and mount/load it with the System.load() method.